# Intel Pin master thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, intel-pin

Is there a way to locate the master thread using Intel PIN? I have an application program in C where I have created some pthreads and wish to do some analysis on them in Pin. I have a PIN_AddThreadStartFunction(), which is the instrumentation routine that is invoked whenever a thread is created. The Pintool is written in C++.

Also is it possible to know from the PIN domain if how many threads are created, through the master thread?

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: Sorry added edit above. The Pintool is written in C++ and the application program is in C.

Comment: What would you consider to be a "*master thread*"? POSIX threads, nor the build-in C11 threads know the concept of a thread being a master.

Comment: You are already intercepting new thread creation. In that routine you can keep track of what you need.

Comment: @alk master thread is the main function of my application C program. So if I create 5 pthreads, then I have a total of 6 threads along with my main program.

Comment: There should be some more accurate, simple term for 'the thread created by the process loader to run _start/main' than 'master' or 'main' but, unfortunately, I know of none:(    I usually describe it as 'main'.  Better than 'master', but still somewhat inaccurate:(

Answer (score 1):

The doc for PIN_AddThreadStartFunction routine says that the callback is called "even for the application's root (initial) thread." So that's how you identify the main, or as you called it, the master thread. It will be the first one for which the THREAD_START_CALLBACK is called. This is also how you find out how many threads are created. You simply enumerate them yourself in the same callback.